# Log Viewing Specific Patient PHI?

Tags: united-states, health

Under the HIPAA and HITECH Regulations (US) is it required for a system to record an audit trail for every time a user accesses any PHI(Protected Health Information)?

As I understand it, an audit trail of user logins is required, as well as any time a user adds, edits, or deletes PHI. Does simply viewing / accessing PHI need to be logged as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply viewing must be logged.

45 CFR 170.210(b) *Record actions related to electronic health information. The date, time, patient identification, and user identification must be recorded when electronic health information is created, modified, **accessed**, or deleted; and an indication of which action(s) occurred and by whom must also be recorded.*

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. If anyone needs it, I found that section on this site:  https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/45/170.210.